# python logging config and access to all methods

Tags: python

I have enabled logging to python code.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s')


logging.info('Log this message')
```

However I am not able to use any of other logging methods. Other methods don't print anything.

```
logging.debug('This is to debug only')
```

Is this related to `level=logging.INFO` ? Which level should i set so it could work with all logging methods?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure your `logging.error` doesn't print anything?

Comment: @zwer logging.debug doesn't print anything.

Comment: that's because your logging level in the `logging.basicConfig()` call is set to `logging.INFO` - switch it to `logging.DEBUG` to use 'lower' levels of logging.

Comment: @zwer If i do that,  It prints everything in debug format.

Comment: @zwer setting  `logging.debug` enables debugging for `requests` and `urllib3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of `logging.DEBUG` level is so that your, or any code you use, can log debug messages - if you don't want debug messages set your level to something higher.

If you still want to print debug messages but want to suppress messages from some of the modules you're using, like the `requests` and `urllib3`, set the level of their loggers to something higher than `logging.DEBUG`, e.g.:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zwer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `level=logging.DEBUG` to log everything.

But `logging.error` should print the error message even with `level=logging.INFO`

Comment: loggin.error works but not `logging.debug`.  If i set level at `logging.DEBUG` it prints debugged version of everything.

Comment: setting  `logging.debug` enables debugging for `requests` and `urllib3`

Answer (score 0):

> **DEBUG** Detailed information, typically of interest only when diagnosing problems.
>
> **INFO** Confirmation that things are working as expected.
>
> **WARNING**   An indication that something unexpected happened, or indicative of some problem in the near future (e.g. ‘disk space low’).
>   The software is still working as expected.
>
> **ERROR** Due to a more serious problem, the software has not been able to perform some function.
>
> **CRITICAL**  A serious error, indicating that the program itself may be unable to continue running.
>
> The default level is WARNING, which means that only events of this
>   level and above will be tracked, unless the logging package is
>   configured to do otherwise.

when you set you level to info you must get `info`,`warning`,`error` and `critical` logs

If you want to log all of level set your level to `logging.DEBUG`

Comment: setting  `logging.debug` enables debugging for `requests` and `urllib3`

Comment: @seoppc but in the question didn't mention to this

Answer (score 0):

The python logging module have multiple level of configuration

- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARNING
- ERROR
- CRITICAL

This logs that will be shown are in the sorted order shown above depending on what level you choose. It will show the selected stage and any other stage "levelled above" the selected stage.

For example, if you choose INFO, the logs will show for all INFO/WARNING/ERROR logs except DEBUG.

This helps in the way that you can sort them by environment variables according to the environment you are currently in, such as you can set it to DEBUG when you are in Development mode, and then set it to WARNING when you are in Production mode.

You can read more about it in the link below

[Python Logging Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

And finally, to give a concrete answer to your question. You should set it to DEBUG to see all the logs.

Hopefully this gives you a better idea on what the python logging module is for!

Cheers!
Max